# Is there a way to make ggplot2 legend show all unique combinations of aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have created a plot which shows two factors, each with two levels. I have shown these using colour and alpha aesthetics. My legend only shows these aesthetics separately. Is there a way to show all unique combinations of the aesthetics with alpha and colour combined? Thank you for your help!

[Picture of plot compared with desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISbme.png)

Here is the relevant code (with some irrelevant parts removed):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Session, y = group_mean, group = FactorA:FactorB))+
  geom_line(aes(colour = FactorA, alpha = FactorB, group = FactorA:FactorB), linetype = "solid", size = 0.7)+
  geom_point(aes(y=group_mean, colour = FactorA, alpha = FactorB, group = FactorA:FactorB), shape = 18, size = 4, position=position_dodge(0.5))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", name = "FactorA")+
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.4, 0.8)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1),
         fill = guide_legend(order = 1), 
         alpha = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

Comment: Could you `dput(head(data))` the data and update the post with that data?

Comment: Without seeing the data, one possibility is to stack (eg `pivot_longer`) and then specify the color/alpha options as you do.